# hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid to String?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am looking to convert hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid to a System String or to a std::string. Can anyone help me out with some simple code to do this? I have been working towards this goal for multiple days now, but every time I get close to the solution, it is converted into gibberish.

Can anyone help me out with a few lines of code (if that much is needed) that will convert "hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid" to a System String or  a std::string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`szHwProfileGuid` is a null-terminated string.

If you are compiling for Ansi/MBCS, `szHwProfileGuid` is declared as `char[]`, which can be assigned directly to a `std::string`, or the `char*`/`SByte*` constructor of `System::String`.

If you are compiling for Unicode, `szHwProfileGuid` is declared as `wchar_t[]`, which can be assigned directly to a `std::wstring`, or the `wchar_t*`/`Char*` constructor of `System::String`. If you need a `std::string`, you will have to convert the Unicode data to Ansi/MBCS using `WideCharToMultiByte()` or `std::wstring_convert` or equivalent.